# Mixitup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, plugins

I don't know why my mixItUp plugin is not working. I followed the instructions on the get started page of the project and I think i followed everything like they said, but it is still not working.

**Code:**

```css
 #piccontainer {
   text-align: justify;
   display: none;
   opacity: 0;
 }
```

```html
<content>
  <div class="filter" data-filter="all">All</div>
  <div class="filter" data-filter=".fotobn">Black and White</div>
  <div class="filter" data-filter=".fotonature">Nature</div>
  <div class="filter" data-filter=".fotopeople">People</div>


  <ul id="piccontainer">
    <li class="mix fotobn">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbdanzafuoco.jpg" alt="The Fire Dancer" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotonature">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbdurdle.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotopeople">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/me.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotopeole fotobn">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbpalestina.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotonature fotobn">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbdurdlebw.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotonature">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumblighthouse.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotonature">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbsicily.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotonature">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbsunset.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>
    <li class="mix fotonature">
      <figure>
        <img src="img/portfolio/thumbwoods.jpg" alt="" />
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
      </figure>
    </li>

  </ul>

</content>




<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->

<script src="js/jquery.mixitup.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    // Start mixitup
    $('#piccontainer').mixItUp();
  });
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

I also tried to use `li` instead of `Div` for the buttons and `Div` instead of `Li` for the images, but still not working. Can you please explain me where the problem is?

Comment: A fiddle would help.

Comment: Ok (my broadband is dead, give me the time to make the jsfiddle :) thank you :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/03a9g9ep/  here is the fiddle

Comment: Seems to worrk fine once you include the mixItUp plugin properly: http://jsfiddle.net/03a9g9ep/1/. Also note that if you are not on mixItUp v2 then the function in all lowercase `mixitup()`.

Comment: Sorry, on my PC the jsfiddle is still not working, I tried to overwrite my local mixitup js with the one you included on js fiddle by URL but doesn't work :/

Comment: OK thank you, is working now, just change the script section :)